# What is the way to save fonts and sizes in Firebase for TextView Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to save Fonts, sizes, and alignments in Firebase for TextView in Swift
so that I can call it in another view.

I was only able to save the color in the Firebase.
Here is the code that shows how I did it.

```
@IBAction func SendBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    if let profileImage = SelecSubStorge , let  profileIMG = profileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
        
        let udidImage = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storeg = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "gs://myproduct-744cb.appspot.com").child(udidImage)
        
        storeg.putData(profileIMG, metadata: nil) { metaDate, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            } else {
                storeg.downloadURL { url, error in
                    let imgSub = url?.absoluteString
                    
                    let ref = Database.database().reference()
                    let sub = ref.child("Sub")
                    let udid = sub.childByAutoId().key
                    let setRef = sub.child(udid!)
                    let value = ["sub": self.subjectLB.text , "detiles" : self.detilesTextview.text , "ImgSub" : imgSub , "SubID" : udid , self.labelColor : "Color"] as [AnyHashable : Any]
                    setRef.setValue(value) { error, ref in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error?.localizedDescription)
                        } else {
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Done", message: "Done Send", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func ChangeColorBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    let colorPicher = UIColorPickerViewController()
    colorPicher.delegate = self
    present(colorPicher, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func colorPickerViewControllerDidSelectColor(_ viewController: UIColorPickerViewController) {
    
    let color = viewController.selectedColor
    detilesTextview.textColor = color
    labelColor = color
}
```

Comment: I answered a similar question a while back ago; what you're asking about is how to save string attributes to Firebase, which cannot be directly done since it doesn't support the NSAttributedString type. e.g. it can only store UTF-8 text. See my answer to this question [Can you save attributed strings to Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61981000/can-you-save-attributed-strings-to-cloud-firestore/62008574#62008574) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this. First, see my answer to this question [Save Attributed Strings To Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61981000/can-you-save-attributed-strings-to-cloud-firestore/62008574#62008574) to see it in done in Firestore.

This answer would apply to the Realmtime Database but he concept is similar.

Cast the attributed string from the textView to NSData and then store it as a string in Firebase.

Firebase supports NSString (String in Swift) but only the actual UTF-8 characters and not the formatting and style.

So the key is to capture the text in the textView as an attributed string, archive it as NSData (Data) and then save the textual version of that, base64Encoded, in Firebase. Then when reading back, do the opposite.

Here's how to store text from a sourceTextView in Firebase

```
func saveAttrStringToFirebase() {
    let attrString = self.sourceTextView.attributedString()

    do {
        let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: attrString, requiringSecureCoding: false)
        let dataString = data.base64EncodedString()

        let ref = self.ref.child("attributed_string") //self.ref points to my Firebase
        ref.setValue(dataString)
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

So then the Firebase will look something like this

```
root
   attributed_string: "YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDB..."
```

Then read back in the value at attributed_string, which will just be a string. Then cast it back to Data and lastly unarchive it

```
func getAttrStringFromFirebase() {
    let ref = self.ref.child("attributed_string")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let dataString = snapshot.value as? String {
            do {
                guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: dataString) else { return }
                guard let attrString = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSAttributedString.self, from: data) else { return }

                self.destinationTextView.textStorage?.append(attrString)
            } catch let err as NSError {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the code that you provided, you can add more fonts, sizes, alignments, or other data by the line :)

```
let value = ["sub": self.subjectLB.text , "detiles" : self.detilesTextview.text , "ImgSub" : imgSub , "SubID" : udid , self.labelColor : "Color"] as [AnyHashable : Any]
```

FYI: Firebase supports a variety of data types but not all, please see this link for [The data types that Cloud Firestore supports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)

Comment: thank you for your reply I know that I want the code in which I can save this

Comment: What does this answer have to do with saving string attributes from a TextVIew, which is what the OP is asking about? For example, they want to store that a string "Hello, World" is bold, underlined and Helvetica, 18 point.

Comment: It is true that I have a text in TextView And I want to save that in the Firebase